# SPARQL - Extract Last part of a URI

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, graphdb

I have a column of URIs from different domains. Example,

```
http://comicmeta.org/cbo/category
http://purl.org/dc/terms/hasVersion
http://schema.org/contributor
```

and so on. I want to extract the last part, i.e, the string after the last slash '/' on each such URI.

Expected results on the above list of URIs:

```
category
hasVersion
contributor
```

How do I write a **generic** SPARQL query to extract this last part from any given URI?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT distinct ?s ?x WHERE { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
    BIND (STRBEFORE(STRAFTER(STR(?s),"/"), " ") as ?x) .
    #To extract the part after the slash '/' and before the end of string indicated by a space ' '. 

}
```

But, this only returns empty strings "".

How can I make this work? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: that is not possible generically - the common way is to use just `strafter()` with a know namespace as second argument - clearly, this only works if you know all namespaces in advance.

Comment: also, `strafter` takes the substring after the first occurrence of the string - which is why your  `STRAFTER(STR(?s),"/")` is useless - and there is no reverse operation in sparql

Comment: given that you'Re using GrpahDB, my suggestion would be to check for any helpful functions, see https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/sparql-functions-reference.html#sparql-spin-functions-and-magic-predicates and if there is no such function simply register your own extension function in JS language: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/javascript-functions.html

Comment: See also the "alternative" for `afn:localname()` here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html

Comment: yeah - extension functions do exists because of SPARQL specs - I didn't mention other triple stores as the question is tagged with `graphdb` (not sure if this holds though or if it could be to other triple stores like Jena)

Comment: STRBEFORE and STRAFTER test the string and return a boolean. Try using REPLACE which can be used to remove a matching regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `REPLACE` is the way:

```
BIND (REPLACE(STR(?s), "^.*/([^/]*)$", "$1") as ?x)
```

This replaces the whole string with only the part found after the last `/` character. Note however that, due to your examples, not all vocabularies use `/` as the delimiter; some also use `#`. Something like `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type` will be turned into `22-rdf-syntax-ns#type`

If you do not want that, you could use something a bit more complicated:

```
BIND (REPLACE(STR(?s), "^.*?([_\\p{L}][-_\\p{L}\\p{N}]*)$", "$1") as ?x)
```

This selects the longest part from the end based on what usually is a valid XML name.